# React hook: useAsyncValue

Tags: react.js, typescript

I wrote this little hook so I could fetch some remote resources:

```
import {DependencyList, useEffect, useRef, useState} from "react";

export default function useAsyncValue<T>(cb: () => Promise<T>, deps?: DependencyList): T | undefined {
    const [value, setValue] = useState<T | undefined>(undefined)
    const nonce = useRef(Symbol())

    useEffect(() => {
        const current = nonce.current = Symbol()
        Promise.resolve(cb()).then(result => {
            if (nonce.current === current) {
                setValue(result)
            }
        })

        return () => {
            nonce.current = Symbol()
        }
    }, deps)

    return value
}
```

Use is like:

```
const value = useAsyncValue(() => fetch("..."))
```

I added a nonce and some deps too so if you do:

```
const value = useAsyncValue(() => fetch(`/get?foo=${foo}`), [foo])
```

Then you `value` will always be the latest result, and you won't have any results out-of-order bugs from older fetch returning after a later fetch.

Are there any problems with this? I don't need to pass the `counter` into the `useEffects` deps list do I?

Answer (score 3):

Your solution is really good, I like that you're using Symbols, but you don't really need to use ref as variable defined in useEffect stays in scope of single useEffect call.

So you can just do this:

```
import { DependencyList, useEffect, useState}  from "react";

export default function useAsyncValue<T>(cb: () => Promise<T>, deps: DependencyList = []): T | undefined {
    const [value, setValue] = useState<T | undefined>(undefined)

    useEffect(() => {
        let aborted = false;

        Promise.resolve(cb()).then(result => {
            if (!aborted) {
                setValue(result)
            }
        })

        return () => {
            aborted = true;
        }
    }, [cb, ...deps])

    return value
}
```

[Playground example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-hk1ugm?file=App.tsx)

Comment: Thanks! What about `cb` -- does it need to be in `deps`? Or will it always refer to the latest version?

Comment: Oh yes, good point. In this case cb should be in deps. I'll edit my answer

Comment: The issue now is that the caller has to be very careful to wrap `cb` in `useCallback` themselves or it'll trigger the effect repeatedly. I think if you wrap `cb` in a ref instead, then whenever deps change it will invoke the current version of cb and avoids the repeated calling issue, without putting the burden on the caller to wrap it. It's kind of weird one though because if you *do* change the cb but not the deps, I guess one would expect it to get invoked immediately, but you usually don't do that.